# HuggingFace Trainer starts distributed training twice

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-trainer, amz-sagemaker-distributed-training

I'm currently trying to run a distributed training job in an aws sagemaker training job. I'm using the SMP library for AWS to parallelize my model. For the training I created the following script:

```
import torch.distributed as dist
import datetime
dist.init_process_group("nccl", timeout=datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200))
import torch.sagemaker as tsm
tsm.init()
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torch
from peft import (
    LoraConfig,
    get_peft_model,
    get_peft_model_state_dict,
    prepare_model_for_int8_training,
)
from datasets import load_from_disk
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, TrainingArguments, Trainer, DataCollatorForSeq2Seq
import argparse

import sys
import os
import logging
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # hyperparameters sent by the client
    parser.add_argument("--batch_size", type=int, default=128)
    parser.add_argument("--per_device_train_batch_size", type=int, default=32)
    parser.add_argument("--model_name", type=str, default="codellama/CodeLlama-7b-hf")
    parser.add_argument("--learn_rate", type=str, default="3e-4")
    parser.add_argument("--warmup_steps", type=int, default=400)
    parser.add_argument("--epochs", type=int, default=1)
    # Data, model and output directories
    parser.add_argument("--output_data_dir", type=str, default=os.environ["SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR"])
    parser.add_argument("--model-dir", type=str, default=os.environ["SM_MODEL_DIR"])
    parser.add_argument("--n_gpus", type=str, default=os.environ["SM_NUM_GPUS"])
    parser.add_argument("--training_dir", type=str, default=os.environ["SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN"])
    parser.add_argument("--test_dir", type=str, default=os.environ["SM_CHANNEL_TEST"])

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()


    # Set up logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.getLevelName("INFO"),
        handlers=[logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)],
        format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
        )

    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        args.model_name,
        load_in_8bit=True,
        torch_dtype=torch.float16
    )
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(args.model_name)

    tokenizer.add_eos_token = True
    tokenizer.pad_token_id = 0
    tokenizer.padding_side = "left"

    # %%
    class MyDataset(Dataset):
        def __init__(self, train=True):
            if train:
                self.dataset = load_from_disk(dataset_path=args.training_dir)
            else:
                self.dataset = load_from_disk(dataset_path=args.test_dir)
        def __len__(self):
            return len(self.dataset)

        def __getitem__(self, idx):
            return self.dataset[idx]

    train_dataset = MyDataset(train=True)
    val_dataset = MyDataset(train=False)

    model.train() # put model back into training mode
    model = prepare_model_for_int8_training(model)

    config = LoraConfig(
        r=16,
        lora_alpha=16,
        target_modules=[
        "q_proj",
        "k_proj",
        "v_proj",
        "o_proj",
    ],
        lora_dropout=0.05,
        bias="none",
        task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
    )
    model = get_peft_model(model, config)
    
    if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
        # keeps Trainer from trying its own DataParallelism when more than 1 gpu is available
        model.is_parallelizable = True
        model.model_parallel = True


    training_args = TrainingArguments(
            per_device_train_batch_size=args.per_device_train_batch_size,
            per_device_eval_batch_size=args.per_device_train_batch_size,
            gradient_checkpointing=True,
            warmup_steps=args.warmup_steps,
            learning_rate=float(args.learn_rate),
            bf16=True,
            logging_steps=1,
            optim="adamw_torch",
            evaluation_strategy="no",
            save_strategy="steps",
            #eval_steps=20,
            save_steps=20,
            output_dir=args.model_dir,
            load_best_model_at_end=False,
            group_by_length=True, # group sequences of roughly the same length together to speed up training
            log_level='debug',
            logging_dir=f"{args.output_data_dir}/logs",
            ddp_find_unused_parameters=False,
            num_train_epochs=args.epochs
        )
    
    def compute_perplexity(pred):
        # Extract the predicted logits from the model output
        logits = pred.predictions
        # Flatten the logits and labels to compute cross-entropy loss
        logits = logits.view(-1, logits.size(-1))
        labels = pred.label_ids.view(-1)
        # Compute cross-entropy loss
        loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(logits, labels)
        # Compute perplexity
        perplexity = torch.exp(loss)
        return {"perplexity": perplexity.item()}

    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=val_dataset,
        args=training_args,
        compute_metrics=compute_perplexity,
        data_collator=DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(
        tokenizer, pad_to_multiple_of=8, return_tensors="pt", padding=True
    ))


    trainer.train()
```

The command that is being executed by sagemaker is the following:
`torchrun --nnodes 1 --nproc_per_node 8 train.py --epochs 1 --learn_rate 0.0003 --model_name codellama/CodeLlama-7b-hf --mp_parameters activation_loading_horizon=2,hybrid_shard_degree=8,sm_activation_offloading=False,tensor_parallel_degree=1 --per_device_train_batch_size 4 --warmup_steps 100`

But for some reason when trainer.train() gets called, the training starts TWICE simultaneously. Do you know how I can change my script so that it runs only ONCE?